# VSCode extension for typescript-based DSL

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings, vscode-extensions

I would like to make a VSCode-based environment for editing typescript-based DSL scripts. The DSL is nothing more than typescript with some dependencies (JS/TS libraries) included by default. In essence, a script file should behave like a .ts file that is part of a project (with tsconfig, dependencies, etc.), but I want scripts to work completely standalone and the project context to be provided by the dev environment.

To make this more concrete, let's say I want to make a DSL for simple drawing using a library like P5, D3 etc. I would like files with .p5ts extension to be editable and runnable as typescript with P5 dependency included, such that intellisense would offer P5 completions, and simple standalone scripts (e.g. `circle(100, 100, 100)`) would immediately work.

Is it possible to accomplish this with a VSCode extension? If so, how? If not, would it be possible to fork VSCode and/or typescript, and add the dependencies to typescript itself?

Comment: You can, but then if someone does not use VSCode and that incredibly specific extension, it won't work for them.

Comment: Yes, I know. It's not intended for general use or portability, but rather to make simple local projects easy when you do have the extension. So what's the best way to add dependencies via an extension?